# Change golang tests/benchmarks time unit results

Tags: go

Currently when doing a golang benchmark on a small function I have in golang I get the following results

```
go test -bench=.
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkBcrypt10-4     1000000000           0.08 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt15-4            1    2607594388 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt18-4            1    20472224268 ns/op
PASS
```

Is there anyway to change the time unit from ns to milisecons or seconds?

## Update:

This is my benchmark file (`bcrypt_test.go`):

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkBcrypt10(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 10)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt15(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 15)
}


func BenchmarkBcrypt18(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 18)
}
```

and my `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func HashPassword(password string, cost int) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), cost)
    return string(bytes), err
}

func CheckPasswordHash(password, hash string) bool {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(password))
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    password := "secret"
    hash, _ := HashPassword(password, 12) // ignore error for the sake of simplicity

    fmt.Println("Password:", password)
    fmt.Println("Hash:    ", hash)

    match := CheckPasswordHash(password, hash)
    fmt.Println("Match:   ", match)
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think there is. The best you can do, I believe, is to use [Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) and print the [BenchmarkResult](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#BenchmarkResult) however you want, but I'm unsure whether that won't conflict with `-bench=.`.

Comment: @mkopriva where would I override the benchmark func? inside the same file as where I wrote the benchmarks? I have included my benchmark file please see update. If you don't mind maybe you can include code sample thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://play.golang.org/p/9aQmPFKDTFJ

Comment: @mkopriva actually yes, the NS values are available in the BenchmarkResult struct.

Answer (score 0):

I have the perfect solution for you!

install the required benchstat tool:

```
go get golang.org/x/perf/cmd/benchstat
go install  golang.org/x/perf/cmd/benchstat
```

Makefile:

```
gather: ; time go test -bench=. | grep --line-buffered  ^Bench | tee -a /tmp/o
stats: ; benchstat /tmp/o
```

Of course, you don't need to use the makefile. Just run the commands directly in the shell if you prefer that.

```
go test -bench=. >/tmp/o
benchstat /tmp/o
```

Sample output:

```
$ make gather stats 
time go test -bench=. | grep --line-buffered  ^Bench | tee -a /tmp/o
BenchmarkBcrypt2-6      1000000000           0.04578 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt4-6      1000000000           0.0007562 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt6-6      1000000000           0.002905 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt8-6      1000000000           0.01147 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt10-6     1000000000           0.04584 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt15-6            1    1462752100 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt18-6            1    11705497684 ns/op
time: Real 0m14.1s  User 0m14.1s  System 0m0.0s
benchstat /tmp/o
name        time/op
Bcrypt2-6   0.05ns ± 0%
Bcrypt4-6   0.00ns ± 1%
Bcrypt6-6   0.00ns ± 0%
Bcrypt8-6   0.01ns ± 0%
Bcrypt10-6  0.05ns ± 1%
Bcrypt18-6   11.7s ± 1%
Bcrypt15-6   1.46s ± 0%
```

modified testfile:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkBcrypt2(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 2) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt4(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 4) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt6(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 6) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt8(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 8) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt10(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 10) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt15(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 15) }
func BenchmarkBcrypt18(b *testing.B) { HashPassword("my pass", 18) }
```

Some useful links:

- https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/14313-benchmark-format.md
- https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/perf

Comment: btw my comp is ~75% faster than yours LOL!

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance... You can try `fmt.Println(b.Elapsed() / time.Duration(b.N))` to workaround

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/floats"
)

const arraySize = 1000000

func BenchmarkGonumSum(b *testing.B) {
    nums := make([]float64, arraySize)
    for i := 0; i < arraySize; i++ {
        nums[i] = float64(i)
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = floats.Sum(nums)
    }
    fmt.Println("number of iterations: ", b.N)
    fmt.Println("elapsed:", b.Elapsed()/time.Duration(b.N))
}
```

this code will produce the next output

```
BenchmarkGonumSum
number of iterations:  1
elapsed: 539.783µs
number of iterations:  100
elapsed: 249.077µs
number of iterations:  4816
elapsed: 188.684µs
number of iterations:  6358
elapsed: 184.344µs
BenchmarkGonumSum-12            6358        184345 ns/op
PASS
```

As you can see on the large iterations count, it is quite close to the standard benchmark output